# Python datetime.datetime not in series of pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp

Tags: python, datetime, series, python-datetime

I don't understand why my datetime isn't found in my series of datetimes:

```
X.key_datetime
Timestamp('2018-12-23 22:34:00')

df['Y'][0]
Timestamp('2018-12-23 22:34:00')
```

Types:

```
type(X.key_datetime)
class 'datetime.datetime'

type(df['Y'])
class 'pandas.core.series.Series'

type(df['Y'][0])
class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'
```

My datetime is equal to the first datetime in the series, yet it is not in the series

```
X.key_datetime == df['Y'][0]
True

X.key_datetime in df['Y']
False

X.key_datetime in df['Y'].values
False
```

I still get the same issue when converting both with pd.to_datetime:

```
pd.to_datetime(X.key_datetime) == pd.to_datetime(df['Y'][0])
True

pd.to_datetime(X.key_datetime) in pd.to_datetime(df['Y'])
False
```

Comment: What is `X` in this case?

Comment: X is a custom object. Within the class self.key_datetime = date: datetime. datetime is a datetime.datetime where we import datetime from datetime for the object.

Comment: df['Y'].isin([X.key_datetime]).any() might work but I'd still like to know why this is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging through the pandas code, it comes down to how the generic `Series` class is setup.  The `__contains__` method (what `in` calls) checks the `_info_axis` attribute. This attribute is setup by the `_setup_axes` method seen here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.25.3/pandas/core/series.py#L4883

Long-story-short, the `in` method for `Series` checks the `index` of the Series object.  Here are some examples to illustrate.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Y': ['2019-11-15', '2019-11-16'], 'Z':['abc', 'def']})
df['Y'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Y)

y = df.Y[0]
y in df.Y
# returns:
False

'abc' in df.Z
# returns:
False
```

This is surprising, but you have to remember that we are checking the `index` of the Series `Y` and `Z`, which is just `RangeIndex(start=0, stop=2, step=1)`.  If we check for the values in the index we see:

```py
0 in df.Y, 1 in df.Z
# returns: 
(True, True)
```

To check if a series contains a value, I would use:

```py
df.Y.eq(y).any()
```

Or in your specific case:

```py
class X:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.key_datetime = datetime.datetime(*args)

x = X(2019, 11, 15)

df.Y.eq(x.key_datetime).any()
# returns:
True
```

Comment: Any issues using df['Y'].isin([X.key_datetime]).any() ?